# Is it possible to share a folder using Ubuntu One outside the home folder?

Tags: ubuntu-one, sharing

As the title suggests, I can't figure out a way to share a folder outside my home folder using Ubuntu One. When browsing to my work partition using Nautilus, every folder has the "Share" option grayed out.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could try using a `mount --bind command`. Something like

```
mount --bind /path/to/folder /home/username/folder_to_sync
```

This should make the contents of `/path/to/folder` available in both places.

Ubuntu-one doesn't support symlinks, but it might support binding mounts. If it does work, you can add a line to `/etc/fstab`

```
/path/to/folder /home/username/folder_to_sync    none    bind    0    0
```

That way it will always mount on boot.

Answer (score 2):

I just did a test, created a new folder */new* and gave it permissions 777. When right clicking on it, Ubuntu One options were greyed out. Also tried creating a shortcut in ~/ dir, but no luck either.

## In short: No, you can't

Answer (score 0):

There are unsupported ways which will work. Think mount points under ~/

Using a bind mount as described above to a folder under ~/ you can sync any folder on your computer with Ubuntu One.

I sync folders on a separate partition with Ubuntu One this way.

Like I said, this is not really supported, but it does work

Comment: -1, can you explain further? Currently, this answer is worthless.

Comment: Using a bind mount as described above to a folder under ~/ you can sync any folder on your computer with Ubuntu One. I sync folders on a separate partition with Ubuntu One this way.

Like I said, this is not really supported, but it does work.

Comment: Can you elaborate and walk us through that in your answer? I'd like to have /etc/logs/ mounted in ~/log-backups. :)